# Is there a tool to determine which Cognos 8.x models are being used?

Tags: report, models, cognos

We have a Cognos 8.x installation with hundreds of reports and dozens of models.   We believe that many of the models are not currently in use on any reports and want to remove those models.   Are there any tools that can be run against Cognos to list which reports are using which model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at motioPI... its a 3rd party app built using the cognos sdk.  You run it against one of your dispatchers and it proves quite handy for these tasks.

http://www.inmotio.com/investigator/home.do

not to mention its free.

Answer (score 0):

There's an audit package that comes with Cognos installations that you can deploy to log user activity. This will help you understand usage and determine any unused models.

Under a normal installation it is located at c8_location/webcontent/samples/Models/Audit/Audit.cpf

With this package you can, amongst other things, list reports that are used, by package. All the while, you're also setting up an auditing tool.

You can refer to your Administration & Security guide to get information on how to setup and use this package.